# jquery .html doesn't apply CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I change content on mu site by using JQUERY's .html() function. After the content have been replaced the content doesn't get any CSS applied and gets the web browsers default style. If i press F5 and reload the page the CSS is applied so the problem is with the JS.

JS:

```
function Go_to_sub_page(page,spage){
    //Get what language that is set
    var lang = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');

    //Get and change content
    $.get('pages/' + page + '/' + spage + '.php',{'lang':lang},function(resp){
        $("#container").html(resp);
    });

    //Change URL
    window.history.replaceState("", "THUNDERSTUDIO: " + page, "?lang=" + lang + "&page=" + page + "&spage=" + spage);
}
```

HTML (That is going to be loaded):

```
<script src="scripts/create_project_selected.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section id="general">
    <span class="label">Title:</span>
    <span id="title" contenteditable>Insert Title</span>
    <select class="font">
        <option id="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option id="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

HTML/PHP (Menu):

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../private_html/allowed_pages.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../private_html/lang.php");

$start =    "<ul>

            </ul>";

$create = "<ul>
                <li><a onclick=\"Go_to_sub_page('create','create')\">{$lang['create']['menu']['create']}<a></li>
                <li><a onclick=\"Go_to_sub_page('create','general')\">{$lang['create']['menu']['general']}<a></li>
            </ul>";

$help = "<ul>

            </ul>";

switch($page){
    case"start":
        echo $start;
        break;
    case"create":
        echo $create;
        break;
    case"help":
        echo $help;
        break;
}
```

CSS 1: None of is used by the html but i paste it as link if you want to have a look.
http://pastebin.com/HPYd51rV

CSS 2 (THE CSS that affect the HTML i want to use):

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>

#general #title{
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;

    color: red;
}
#general #title:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

lang.php is file that control the language on the site. Has no impact on this problem.
allowed_pages.php only impacts the menu.

Comment: Best to post the CSS.

Comment: Updated the question with the CSS.

Comment: Can you give an example response (from the javascript console) of the ajax request? Is it returning a full page with <html></html> tags?

Comment: Summarized everything here. http://pastebin.com/jTu5ZKgk
I checked Firefox's inspector, Firefox's Debugger and Firebug. Firebug told me nothing.

Comment: Is it possible to share a URL for me to look at?

Comment: It's local but i could upload it but it will take around 10-20 min I guess.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll be around for a bit.

Comment: I had to recode a bit so you don't need to login.
I got a lot of error the i uploaded it but they should not make any different. On the top menu click "CREATE". Then click "Baka" and after that click "General" on the menu to the left.

[link](http://dev.thunderstudio.org/create/)

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is mega confusing, the only reason I can think of this happening is you're loading your `<link href="css/create.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in one 'view' and then overwriting this by replacing that view with a new view (that doesn't link to the CSS style sheet):

```
<script src="scripts/create_project_selected.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section id="general">
    <span class="label">Title:</span>
    <span id="title" contenteditable>Insert Title</span>
    <select class="font">
        <option id="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option id="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Solutions:

- Include a link to the CSS sheet in every 'view' you want the CSS to be effective in.
- Or, have a section somewhere in your page that you can `$(element).append("<link href='' rel='stylesheet' id='unquie_indentifier_so_it_can_be_removed_later' / >")`

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I'm not totally sure then. I've worked on ajax heavy projects where it loaded pages dynamically and it became such a mess that I decided the scrap the project after 4 months of work and start again with Laravel.